# Cocoa NSComboBox scroll bar and click arrow

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have two problems about objective c cocoa NSComboBox.

1. How can I set the scroll bar always visible, not just scroll the list.
2. Can I open the list by clicked the text, not just clicking the arrows.

Answer (score 0):

1. When the pop window open , you can find the scrollview inside the popup window and change the visible property of that .Please refer this code : https://github.com/ilg/IGResizableComboBox
   steps :

a) Find the combo box window

```
- (NSWindow *)comboBoxPopUpWindow
{
    NSWindow *child = nil;
    for (child in [[self window] childWindows]) {

            if ([[child className] isEqualToString:@"NSComboBoxWindow"]) {
                break;
            }

        }

    return child;
}
```

b) iterate the subviews of the windows content view

```
-(NSScrollView*)findScrollView:(NSWindow*)window
{
    NSView *contentView = [window contentView];
    for(NSView *view in [contentView subViews]){
     if([[view className] isEqualToString:@"NSScrollView"]){
       return scrollView;
      }
   }

}
```

c) Modify scrollview property

2. You can override the mouse down and open the list. For opening the list, please refer this : [How to programmatically open an NSComboBox's list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4499262/how-to-programmatically-open-an-nscomboboxs-list)

Comment: override the mouse down and open the list is work. I added the NSButton and call the function you provided.

But i don't know how to set the scrollview. i want the scroll bar show for long time when the combobox list opened.

Comment: @HipSize , Modified the answer