# How to expand NSPopUpButton in Swift programmatically?

Tags: swift, cocoa

I am trying to expand `NSPopUpButton` with Swift. For a native OSX app, I have to override a design like a screenshot below.

[image]

My purpose is adding a button as with `down_icon`and when I click it the popup button must expand. I can't do it in `NSPopUpButton` but in this question thread, this is possible for `NSComboBox`. [Question Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4499262/how-to-programmatically-open-an-nscomboboxs-list)

As I tried in NSComboBox,

`comboBoxCell.performSelector(Selector("popUp:"))`

code block not worked for `NSPopUpButton` because of there is no selector for NSPopUpButton for popping up.

Also, try

`phoneCodesPopup.setAccessibilityExpanded(true)`

but it is not expanded.

How can I open `NSPopUpButton` programmatically?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I just realised your question is contradictory: you said "I can't do [the design shown in the picture] in `NSPopUpButton`" so why are you still using an `NSPopupButton`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike `NSComboBox`, clicking on `NSPopoverButton`, anywhere, will make it pop up, so you just need [`performClick`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscontrol/1428974-performclick):

```
yourPopup.performClick(nil)
```

Comment: I will try it asap

Comment: sorry for latency, it worked like charm. How can I understand it to get 
 where can I use `performClick` or `setAccessibilityExpanded` ? Is there any reasonable perform documentation of it? I can not get it from the Apple documents when I read it. Thanks by the way 

Comment: @elia I haven't had much experience with `setAccessibilityExpanded`... I'm just not familiar with Accessibility in general, really. For `performClick`, it's basically an educated guess :) This is my thought process: I know that `NSPopoverButton` is a subclass `NSButton`, and I click on it to expand it, so naturally I reframed the problem as "how do I programmatically click an `NSButton`". Well, I know `performClick` does that.

Comment: so maybe lack of my experience on `Accessibility`. Can you recommend a blog post or tutorial for me to get better on this topic?.

Comment: @elia maybe I haven’t made it clear, but I really don’t know much about accessibility, and do not have the experience to recommend a tutorial. But have you tried googling “macOS swift accessibility”? That’s what I would do if I wanted to learn more about it.

Comment: I was actually looking for a tutorial to better understand the topics we were talking about. Sorry for not being clear, thank you for the answer.